# PHP validation not working insert query?

Tags: php, mysql

Validation is dine.now i am confused that where to write insert query in this code

```
<td><input type="text" name="t4"></td>
        <td>
        <div class="ans">
        <?php if(isset($_GET['ans1'])){
            $txt1=$_GET['ans1'];
            echo $txt1;
        }?>
        <?php if(isset($_GET['ans4'])){
            $txt4=$_GET['ans4'];
            echo $txt4;
        }?>
        </div>
        </td>
```

signup.php

```
<?php
    include "db.php";
    $user=$_POST['t1'];
    $pass=md5($_POST['t2']);
    $confirm=md5($_POST['t3']);
    $email=$_POST['t4'];
    if($pass == $confirm && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$email)){
    mysql_query("insert into registor(username,password,email) values('$user','$pass','$email')")or die(mysql_error());
    $query="select* from registor where username like '" . 
        mysql_real_escape_string($user) . "'";
    $res =mysql_query($query);
    if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
      $txt3="username already taken";
      header("location:signup-index.php?ans3=$txt3");
    }
    $query2="select* from registor where email like '" . 
        mysql_real_escape_string($email) . "'";
    $res2 =mysql_query($query2);
    if(mysql_num_rows($res2) > 0) {
      $txt4="email already taken";
      header("location:signup-index.php?ans4=$txt4");
     }
    }
    else{
        $txt2="Password not match";
        $txt1 = "Please enter valid email"; 
        header("location:signup-index.php?ans1=$txt1&ans2=$txt2");
     }
      ?>
```

where to add insert mysql query in this code.is there any better way to make form.
record is inserted but it shows email already taken on index.html

Comment: What you want to insert? and please read this http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php

Comment: thanks for reply..I want to insertthis query= "insert into table values $user....".
where  to write this code anywhere then the data is inserted without checking the validations.

Comment: You want to insert the user in registor without the vallidation??

Comment: no ..i want to insert with validations.I mean if all the conditions are true than insert record else not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your comment and problem mention in your question. I have found few points here.

1) Your both select query is wrong

```
 select* from registor .....
```

should be

```
 select * from registor.....
       ^
```

2) Your write your insert query when your all validation correct. you have written your insert query in starting of the loop . it always insert record before validating.

**signup.php**

```
<?php

include "db.php";
$user = $_POST['t1'];
$pass = md5($_POST['t2']);
$confirm = md5($_POST['t3']);
$email = $_POST['t4'];
if ($pass == $confirm && !preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/", $email)) {
    $errorFlag = 0;
    $query = "select * from registor where username like '" .
            mysql_real_escape_string($user) . "'";
    $res = mysql_query($query);
    if (mysql_num_rows($res) > 0) {
        $errorMsg = "username already taken";
        $errorFlag = 1;
    }
    $query2 = "select * from registor where email like '" .
            mysql_real_escape_string($email) . "'";
    $res2 = mysql_query($query2);
    if (mysql_num_rows($res2) > 0) {
        $errorMsg = "email already taken";
        $errorFlag = 1;
    }

    if ($errorFlag) {
        header("location:signup-index.php?msg=$errorMsg");
    } else {
        mysql_query("insert into registor (username,password,email) values('$user','$pass','$email')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
} else {
    $txt2 = "Password not match";
    $txt1 = "Please enter valid email";
    header("location:signup-index.php?ans1=$txt1&ans2=$txt2");
}
```

Display Error msg like this:-

```
<td>
    <div class="ans">
        <?php
        if (isset($_GET['msg'])) {
            echo $_GET['msg'];
        }
        ?>
    </div>
</td>
```

Comment: any syntax,that how to write insert query with loop.
i want the data will insert after checking all validations.
i am facing problem now is,the data is inserted without checking the validations.
thanks for your reply sir. :)

Comment: Yes your data will insert after validation . Please try my solution first :)

Comment: its ready appreciated...Thanks alot..Its working fine now.

Comment: Pleasure to help you. enjoy learning :)